# how to write a formula method that converts long to wide

Tags: r, class, methods, tidyr, reshape2

In the [twoway package](https://github.com/friendly/twoway), I have a `twoway.default()` method that takes a matrix or data frame and applies Tukey's methods for the analysis of twoway tables.

Example:

```
> data(taskRT)
> taskRT
       topic1 topic2 topic3 topic4
Easy     2.43   3.12   3.68   4.04
Medium   3.41   3.91   4.07   5.10
Hard     4.21   4.65   5.87   5.69
> twoway(taskRT)

Mean decomposition (Dataset: "taskRT")
Residuals bordered by row effects, column effects, and overall

         topic1    topic2    topic3    topic4      roweff   
       + --------- --------- --------- --------- + ---------
Easy   | -0.055833  0.090833  0.004167 -0.039167 : -0.864167
Medium |  0.119167  0.075833 -0.410833  0.215833 : -0.059167
Hard   | -0.063333 -0.166667  0.406667 -0.176667 :  0.923333
       + ......... ......... ......... ......... + .........
coleff | -0.831667 -0.288333  0.358333  0.761667 :  4.181667
```

I want to extend this with a formula method that takes a data frame and a formula of the form `response ~ row + column`, reshapes this from long to wide and then calls the default method. I know several ways to do this directly in the console, but I can't seem to get any of them to work in a formula method function.

Thus, for this data in long format, with the cell value called `RT` and the row and column variables as `task` and `topic`, I'd like to get the same results with a call of

```
twoway(RT ~ task + topic, data=long)
```

At top-level, in the console I can do this in various ways, starting from a `long` version of the same data.

```
library(reshape2)
long <- melt(as.matrix(taskRT))
colnames(long) <- c("task", "topic", "RT")
```

Convert back to wide format, and call `twoway()` on that:

```
# convert wide to long: dcast
(wide <- dcast(long, task ~ topic, value.var="RT"))
twoway(wide[,-1])

# tidyr::spread
library(tidyr)
(wide <- spread(long, key=topic, value=RT))
twoway(wide[,-1])

# base, unstack
wide <- unstack(long, form = RT ~ topic)
rownames(wide) <- unique(long$task)
twoway(wide)
```

Below is an initial sketch of a `twoway.formula` method.  The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to use the results of parsing the formula object and the associated data frame in the function to construct a call in the function that would result in a wide matrix or data frame suitable for passing to the default method. So far, I've been trying various forms of `dcast` within the function, shown as comments, none of which give me joy.

```
#' Initial sketch for a twoway formula method
#'
#' Doesn't do anything useful yet, but the idea is to be able to use a
#' formula for a twoway table in long form, e.g.,
#' twoway(response ~ row + col, data=mydata)
#'
#' @param formula A formula of the form \code{response ~ rowvar + colVAR}
#' @param data The name of the data set
#' @param subset An expression to subset the data (unused)
#' @param na.action What to do with NAs? (unused)
#' @param ... other arguments, passed down
#' @importFrom stats terms
#'
twoway.formula <- function(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...) {

  if (missing(formula) || !inherits(formula, "formula"))
    stop("'formula' missing or incorrect")
  if (length(formula) != 3L)
    stop("'formula' must have both left and right hand sides")
  tt <- if (is.data.frame(data))
    terms(formula, data = data)
  else terms(formula)
  if (any(attr(tt, "order") > 1))
    stop("interactions are not allowed")

  rvar <- attr(terms(formula[-2L]), "term.labels")
  lvar <- attr(terms(formula[-3L]), "term.labels")
  rhs.has.dot <- any(rvar == ".")
  lhs.has.dot <- any(lvar == ".")
  if (lhs.has.dot || rhs.has.dot)
    stop("'formula' has '.' in left or right hand sides")
  m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  edata <- eval(m$data, parent.frame())
  lhs <- formula[[2]]
  rhs <- formula[[3]]

  #  wide <- dcast(data=edata, formula=as.formula(rhs), value.var=lhs )
  #  wide <- dcast(data=edata, value.var=lhs)
  #  wide <- dcast(data=edata, rvar[1] ~ rvar[2], value.var=cvar)
  #  wide <- dcast(data=edata, list(.(rvar[1], .(rvar[2], .(cvar)))))
#browser()
  stop("The formula method is not yet implemented.")

  # call the default method on the wide data set
  twoway(wide)
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's alittle confusing on what you are looking for. Are you trying to write a function that will convert any dataset from long to wide format?

Comment: No, you don't understand the wider context of my question, which was clearly stated: how to do this within the context of an S3 formula method.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`...

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

twoway.formula <- function(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...) {

  if (missing(formula) || !inherits(formula, "formula"))
    stop("'formula' missing or incorrect")
  if (length(formula) != 3L)
    stop("'formula' must have both left and right hand sides")
  tt <- if (is.data.frame(data)) {
    terms(formula, data = data)
  } else { terms(formula) }
  if (any(attr(tt, "order") > 1))
    stop("interactions are not allowed")

  rvar <- attr(terms(formula[-2L]), "term.labels")
  lvar <- attr(terms(formula[-3L]), "term.labels")
  rhs.has.dot <- any(rvar == ".")
  lhs.has.dot <- any(lvar == ".")
  if (lhs.has.dot || rhs.has.dot)
    stop("'formula' has '.' in left or right hand sides")
  m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  edata <- eval(m$data, parent.frame())
  lhs <- formula[[2]]
  rhs <- formula[[3]]

  wide <- 
    edata %>% 
    select(one_of(rvar, lvar)) %>% 
    spread(key = rvar[2], value = lvar) %>% 
    column_to_rownames(rvar[1])

  # call the default method on the wide data set
  twoway(wide)
}


library(twoway)
data(taskRT)

library(reshape2)
long <- melt(as.matrix(taskRT))
colnames(long) <- c("task", "topic", "RT")

twoway(taskRT)

twoway(RT ~ task + topic, data = long)
```

Comment: Lovely; thanks.  There is one error: should be `wide <- edata %>% ...`

Comment: Q: I don't understand the use of `one_of()` here.

Comment: `one_of()` selects variables whose name is equal to any of the strings passed to it (technically, I suppose it converts the strings to symbols and  passes them to `select`, or something like that)

Comment: changed `data` to `edata`... not really sure what the purpose of that is... it worked either way for me

Comment: and if you were wondering why I was selecting specific variables, it was just a defensive approach assuming you might pass data that had more than the three variables used in the formula